# Can PHP read and interpret data from a txt file?

Tags: php, mysql

I am very new and unfamiliar with PHP so please forgive me if this question is elementary level.

I want to paginate my article index with PHP. But all of the tutorials I could find on Google required that the data to be paginated be stored on some kind of database. I am only allowed two MySql databases on my host, and I kind of want to save those databases for something more important. I randomly had this idea to replace the MySql database with a .txt file, and put my data on there. Since I am storing a list of the pages on my website anyway, so I don't care if people can see the text file.

Here is how I want the text file to be laid out (each field is separated by colons):

```
date:article name:URL:catagory:tags:special notes
```

I want to know if this is even possible, and if it is, are there any resources that provide information on how to do this?

One other possibility is to replace the .txt file with an XML file. Would this be a better option?

Comment: This will probably get closed as off topic - but in short yes. look at `file_get_contents` and `explode` in the php manual. and to circumvent your database limit - just use different table prefixes for different projects. eg test_Table1, test_Table2, ...

Comment: Thanks! I am also considering using an XML page. Is that possible to?

Comment: there are php libraries for xml processing also, but seriously - just abuse table prefixes to cram more data into your databases.

Comment: Unless it's a super unprofessional hoster, most PHP installations have a SQLite binding.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,ofcourse php can.You should study about the php file handling for better understanding of this.You can use file_get_contents() for reading the flie & then explode() it.Its very simple.

Answer (score 0):

`PHP` provides a lot of functions for text processing. Take a look at the [`Strings`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.strings.php) section of the documentation. Regarding the file processing, read the section about [`Filesystem functions`](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php).

Some functions that can help you:

- [`file_get_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) - read the entire content of a file and return a string; it is paired by [`file_put_contents()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) - replace the content of a file (or create the file if it does not exist) with the string value passed as argument;
- [`file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) - read the content of a file, split it into lines and return an array of strings (the lines);
- [`str_getcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) can be used to split the lines produced by `file()` into components ([comma-separated values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values));
- [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) - split a string into pieces using a separator (does not handle any quoting or escaping as `str_getcsv()` does); paired by [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) - joins the items of an array using a glue string;
- [`fgetcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) - read a line from an open file and split it into components (CSV); it is paired by [`fputcsv()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php);
- in order to use `fgetcsv()`/`fputcsv()` and other [functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php) that read or write blocks of data from/to a file you need to open the file first (use [`fopen()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php)) and close it after you end processing (use [`fclose()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fclose.php)).

This is just a small list of functions you should check. You can find more information about them (and others) in the [PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/).

#### On a second thought

Using text files instead of databases is not a good idea on a system that is accessed concurrently by many client (like it happens on a website). If the code only reads them then it's ok but if it also attempts to write them, sooner or later you will end up with data corruption because there is no reliable way to prevent two processes (two instances of your script) to process the file simultaneously.

Before deciding to use text files, also consider the good suggestions you got in the question's comments.

@mario [suggests to use SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888014/can-php-read-and-interpret-data-from-a-txt-file#comment47899900_29888014) (check the output of [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), search for `SQLite` and `pdo_sqlite`); it is a good choice for small databases and it is `SQL` - if you access it using [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) you can switch later to `MySQL` or other `RDBMS` with very little effort.

@pala_ [suggests to use (and abuse) table prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29888014/can-php-read-and-interpret-data-from-a-txt-file#comment47899874_29888014). This means to use a common prefix for all the table names that belong to the same application. `WordPress` installer uses this trick to allow the installation of several WP instances in the same database.